# search not working when using Sieve jquery for Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am using Sieve jQuery plugin to search for data. I have the following html code and I am having a hard time trying to make this plugin work. Below is my html structure.

Below is what I have tried so far. In document.ready section,

```
a) $("#divvalue .popovercontent").sieve({ itemSelector: "a" });
b) $(".popovercontent").sieve({ itemSelector: "a" }); 
c) $("#divvalue div.popovercontent").sieve({ itemSelector: "a" });
```

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="panel-body" id="divvalue" style="height: 92px; text-align: center; color: rgb(115, 137, 3);">
            <h2 id="h2value">2</h2>
            <a tabindex="0" class="hidden-xs" id="avalue" aria-    describedby="popover584721" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="run 
<button type='button' class='close pull-right visible-phone' data-dismiss='popover'>×</button><br /><br />
<input type='text' id='testrun' style='width:120px; font-weight:normal; font-size:small; color:gray' placeholder='Search' />" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<a href=http://abc/xyz</a><br />">Display</a><div class="popover fade bottom in" id="popover584721" role="tooltip" style="left: 13.95px; top: 121.13px; display: block;"><div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div><h3 class="popover-title">Running <button class="close pull-right visible-phone" type="button" data-dismiss="popover">×</button><br><br><input id="testrun" style="width: 120px; color: gray; font-size: small; font-weight: normal;" type="text" placeholder="Search"></h3><div class="popover-content"><a href="http://Test123</a><br></div></div>
```

Comment: Please provide information about the expected result and the result you actually get.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Sorry if my question was not enough clear. I have a list of records inside popover. I am trying add Search functionality (Search box) inside popover to filter/search any particular record from that list.